# Не включается камера в Android

Tags: android

Хочу сделать программу, которая будет светить фонариком при входящем смс.
Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xold.my.myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

IncomingSms.java:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.util.Log;


public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Camera camera;
    Parameters params;
    private boolean hasFlash;


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        hasFlash = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!hasFlash) {
            try {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "netu vspishki!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("1 Ошибка, невозможно запустить: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            if (camera == null) {
                try {
                    camera.open();
                    params = camera.getParameters();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e("2 Ошибка, невозможно запустить: ", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();


            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "naverno led vkluchilas!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

2 Ошибка, невозможно запустить:﹕

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Выводтся ли **1 Ошибка,...** или **2 Ошибка,...** ?

Comment: 2 ошибка .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифест необходимо добавить permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сделать

```
camera.open();
```

так

```
camera = Camera.open();
```

или так

```
camera = Camera.open(0);
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло